# Clearing Contents of log file Python doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have stumbled upon a problem. I have code which should append the contents of `logfile` on `all_logfile` every time the code runs.

Note:

- Log file is the file that needs to be overwriten by the new logs.
- `logfile` is the path to the file so: `logfile = "path"`.
- `all_logfile` is the file where the old logs from the `logfile` is appended.

This is the appending code:

```
with open(logfile) as f:
   with open(all_logfiles, "a") as f1:
      for line in f:
         f1.write(line)
```

The code above works, however, I have to clear the contents of `logfile`. The `filemode= 'w'` doesn't work for me.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                filename=logfile,
                filemode='w')
```

And opening the file in 'w' mode doesn't also work.

```
with open('yourlog.log', 'w'):
pass
```

Is there any way I could clear the contents of the log file before writing new logs in it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does `open('file.log', 'w').close()` work? Maybe there is a permissions issue?

Comment: when I try to add that and run it, the file is being overwritten by this: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: What about `'wb'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the data from the logfile after writing it to all_logfile, you can just truncate the file after the data has been written to all_logfile. Below code should work:

```
with open(logfile, "r+") as f:
    with open(all_logfiles, "a") as f1:
    for line in f:
        f1.write(line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Same thing still persists, when I try to open the file, it contains this: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

Comment: Try to open the file in binary mode and see if that works. "rb+"